# Update new Android Studio Flamingo | 2022.2.1 error in my old Project on Flutter

Tags: flutter, kotlin-gradle-plugin, android-studio-flamingo

I am updating new android studio and run my project at that time show error.

The Android Gradle plugin supports only Kotlin Gradle plugin version 1.5.20 and higher.
The following dependencies do not satisfy the required version:
project ':wakelock' -> org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:1.3.50

change my .biuld.gradle file but not any solution

```
    ext.kotlin_version = '1.6.10'
    repositories {
        google()
        mavenCentral()
    }

    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:7.3.0'
        classpath "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:$kotlin_version"
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        google()
        mavenCentral()
    }
}

rootProject.buildDir = '../build'
subprojects {
    project.buildDir = "${rootProject.buildDir}/${project.name}"
}
subprojects {
    project.evaluationDependsOn(':app')
}

tasks.register("clean", Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir
}
```

pubspec.yaml file

```
name: power_solution
description: A new Flutter project.
# The following line prevents the package from being accidentally published to
# pub.dev using `flutter pub publish`. This is preferred for private packages.
publish_to: 'none' # Remove this line if you wish to publish to pub.dev

# The following defines the version and build number for your application.
# A version number is three numbers separated by dots, like 1.2.43
# followed by an optional build number separated by a +.
# Both the version and the builder number may be overridden in flutter
# build by specifying --build-name and --build-number, respectively.
# In Android, build-name is used as versionName while build-number used as versionCode.
# Read more about Android versioning at https://developer.android.com/studio/publish/versioning
# In iOS, build-name is used as CFBundleShortVersionString while build-number is used as CFBundleVersion.
# Read more about iOS versioning at
# https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/General/Reference/InfoPlistKeyReference/Articles/CoreFoundationKeys.html
# In Windows, build-name is used as the major, minor, and patch parts
# of the product and file versions while build-number is used as the build suffix.
version: 1.0.0+1

environment:
  sdk: '>=3.0.2 <4.0.0'

# Dependencies specify other packages that your package needs in order to work.
# To automatically upgrade your package dependencies to the latest versions
# consider running `flutter pub upgrade --major-versions`. Alternatively,
# dependencies can be manually updated by changing the version numbers below to
# the latest version available on pub.dev. To see which dependencies have newer
# versions available, run `flutter pub outdated`.
dependencies:
  flutter:
    sdk: flutter


  # The following adds the Cupertino Icons font to your application.
  # Use with the CupertinoIcons class for iOS style icons.
  cupertino_icons: ^1.0.2

  # state management
  flutter_riverpod: ^2.3.6

  # networking
  dio: ^5.1.2
  pretty_dio_logger: ^1.3.1
  shared_preferences: ^2.1.1
  google_fonts: any

  # widget
  timer_count_down: ^2.2.2
  url_launcher: ^6.1.11
  flutter_typeahead: ^4.6.1
  chewie:
  video_player: ^2.2.5
  http: ^0.13.5
  razorpay_flutter: ^1.3.4
  readmore: ^2.2.0
  google_maps_flutter:
  flutter_rating_bar: ^4.0.1
  flutter_phone_direct_caller: ^2.1.1
  flutter_staggered_grid_view: ^0.6.2
  cached_network_image: ^3.2.2
  card_slider: ^1.0.5
  carousel_slider: ^4.2.1
  flutter_statusbarcolor_ns: ^0.5.0
  font_awesome_flutter: ^10.4.0
  flutter_spinkit: ^5.1.0
  flutter_svg: ^0.23.0
  persistent_bottom_nav_bar: ^5.0.2
  file_picker: ^5.3.2
  video_thumbnail: ^0.5.3
  path_provider: ^2.0.15

  # show msg notification
  elegant_notification: ^1.10.0

dev_dependencies:
  flutter_test:
    sdk: flutter

  # The "flutter_lints" package below contains a set of recommended lints to
  # encourage good coding practices. The lint set provided by the package is
  # activated in the `analysis_options.yaml` file located at the root of your
  # package. See that file for information about deactivating specific lint
  # rules and activating additional ones.
  flutter_lints: ^2.0.0

# For information on the generic Dart part of this file, see the
# following page: https://dart.dev/tools/pub/pubspec

# The following section is specific to Flutter packages.
flutter:

  # The following line ensures that the Material Icons font is
  # included with your application, so that you can use the icons in
  # the material Icons class.
  uses-material-design: true

  # To add assets to your application, add an assets section, like this:
  assets:
    - assets/image/
    - assets/svg/
  #   - images/a_dot_ham.jpeg

  # An image asset can refer to one or more resolution-specific "variants", see
  # https://flutter.dev/assets-and-images/#resolution-aware

  # For details regarding adding assets from package dependencies, see
  # https://flutter.dev/assets-and-images/#from-packages

  # To add custom fonts to your application, add a fonts section here,
  # in this "flutter" section. Each entry in this list should have a
  # "family" key with the font family name, and a "fonts" key with a
  # list giving the asset and other descriptors for the font. For
  # example:
  fonts:
   - family: CustomIcons
     fonts:
       - asset: assets/font/CustomIcons.ttf

  #         style: italic
  #   - family: Trajan Pro
  #     fonts:
  #       - asset: fonts/TrajanPro.ttf
  #       - asset: fonts/TrajanPro_Bold.ttf
  #         weight: 700
  #
  # For details regarding fonts from package dependencies,
  # see https://flutter.dev/custom-fonts/#from-packages
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0xfx9.jpg)

```
run terminal in -> flutter doctor -v

Windows PowerShell
Copyright (C) Microsoft Corporation. All rights reserved.
    • Framework revision 796c8ef792 (3 weeks ago), 2023-06-13 15:51:02 -0700
    • Engine revision 45f6e00911
    • Dart version 3.0.5
    • DevTools version 2.23.1

[√] Windows Version (Installed version of Windows is version 10 or higher)

[√] Android toolchain - develop for Android devices (Android SDK version 30.0.3)
    • Android SDK at C:\Users\Alpesh\AppData\Local\Android\sdk                  
    • Platform android-33, build-tools 30.0.3                                   
    • Java binary at: C:\Program Files\Android\Android Studio\jbr\bin\java      
    • Java version OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 17.0.6+0-b2043.56-9586694)
    • All Android licenses accepted.                                            
                                                                                
[√] Chrome - develop for the web                                                
    • Chrome at C:\Program Files\Google\Chrome\Application\chrome.exe           
                                                                                
[√] Android Studio (version 2022.2)
    • Android Studio at C:\Program Files\Android\Android Studio
    • Flutter plugin can be installed from:
       https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/9212-flutter
    • Dart plugin can be installed from:
       https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/6351-dart
    • Java version OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 17.0.6+0-b2043.56-9586694)

[√] Connected device (3 available)
    • Windows (desktop) • windows • windows-x64    • Microsoft Windows [Version 10.0.19045.2846]
    • Chrome (web)      • chrome  • web-javascript • Google Chrome 114.0.5735.199
    • Edge (web)        • edge    • web-javascript • Microsoft Edge 114.0.1823.67

[√] Network resources
    • All expected network resources are available.

! Doctor found issues in 1 category.
```

Comment: can u run `flutter doctor -v` & paste it on your question

Comment: Please check i was added.

Comment: Same problem here. Did you find a solution?